# Running tensorflow-2.0 from docker container

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Am currently running `tensorflow-2.0` with docker and it works fine in the terminal (ubuntu 18.04). However I want to run a jupyter notebook instance in the browser and running `docker run -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow` isn't providing a link to run in the browser. Any guide on how I can go about this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tensorflow/tensorflow` docker image does not ship with Jupyter inside. You have to run one of the [jupyter-enabled images](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags?page=1&name=jupyter), like `tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-jupyter`.

Kind.